# Умей простить, умей забыть, увидеть свет во мгле(,) и доброту умей ценить и радость на земле

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены, и

Нужна эта запятая в песне Боярского «Поверь в себя»?

> А чтобы горе пережить, достаточно вполне раз навсегда тебе решить — прекрасна жизнь вдвойне. Умей простить, умей забыть, увидеть свет во мгле(,) и доброту умей ценить и радость на земле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я считаю, что правильная пунктуация должна быть такой:

[Ты] *Умей простить, умей забыть,

Увидеть свет во **мгле,**

**И** доброту умей ценить,

**И** радость на земле.*

Запятые ставятся **на разном основании**.
Первая группа однородных членов (сказуемые): *умей простить, умей забыть,* [умей] *увидеть*;
вторая группа однородных членов ("разделенные" дополнения с повторяющимся союзом "и"), относящихся к сказуемому "умей ценить": [и] *доброту*, [и] *радость*.

У автора, Н. Шемятенковой, указанные запятые имеются.

[Поверь в себя](http://www.notarhiv.ru/ruskomp/fel%27zman/noti/1%20(105).pdf) (Нотный архив России)